# Vue as a widget on a random site. Styles not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**Task**: Create a vue widget that can be connected to supporters sites.

**Example**:

```
<my-widget />
<script src='random url to widget'></script>
```

**What happened to do:**
Application build, dist folder - 1 js file. I connect on another site through a script and `<div id='my-widget'></div>`

It appears on the page, but there are no styles. (If important, then the styles are written in scss). `vue3, webpack`. What am I doing wrong? Or maybe there is a more concise solution? Haven't dealt with this case before.

Comment: Are you building it as a Vue app and mounting it to the element with the ID `my-widget`? Or as a Vue component? Something else? I'm afraid you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Yes, I created a small application (let's say a calculator). in main.js ```createApp(App).use(router).mount('#widget-calculator')```. And then ```npm run build```, i got folder dist.

Comment: Is that example code for the app or the consumer? And is it correct/actually what your using?

Comment: Yes, it's a widget. (app). For example, ```A = consumer```, ```B = widget (calculator)```. I need to create a widget and add it in ```A```.

Comment: I mean, is that code block labeled "Example" in the consumer or the widget code? The consumer would obviously need to use something like `<div id="my-widget"></div>`, not `<my-widget>`.